# How to include a html which contains angularjs binding as pop up modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angularjs. I have a html page   which I need to include in another html page as pop up (both the html page have contents loaded from controller). It is working fine when I use router to move between pages. But I want the second page to be show as a pop up modal with a button and text box whose value also I need in controller. Simply put I need a preview page before I make the form submit. I went through several sites and they have asked me make use of templates but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: Add your code to the question.

Comment: Share what have you done.

Answer (score 0):

I used bootstrap modal. Make sure you make use of the correct bootstrap version for showing and hiding the modal from javascript file also.

Answer (score 0):

use angular-modal-service. You need to include this service in your controller. This service has the option to edit header and submit option in your controller http://dwmkerr.github.io/angular-modal-service/